Azure Functions(関数アプリ)にデプロイしても反映されません
VSCodeのプラグインを使用し、デプロイに成功していますが下記のままです。
プロジェクトフォルダ/index.jsにはExpressでTwitterにログインできるようにする処理があります。
なぜデプロイに成功しているにもかかわらず、関数が追加されていないのでしょうか？
Azure Functionsの状態:

ソースコード
プロジェクトフォルダ/function.json
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "anonymous",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": [
                "get",
                "post"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "res"
        }
    ],
    "scriptFile": "index.js",
    "entryPoint": "hoge"
}

プロジェクトフォルダ/host.json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "Function": "Information"
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    }
}

プロジェクトフォルダ/package.json
{
    "name": "twitter-login-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Twitter login with Express on Azure Functions",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "func start",
        "build": "echo 'No build step required for Azure Functions'",
        "test": "echo 'No tests specified'"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.7.7",
        "express": "^4.21.0",
        "oauth": "^0.10.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "20.x"
    }
}


"VSCode のプラグイン" とは具体的に何を使用しているのかと、「デプロイには成功している」と判断した材料を質問に追記してみてください。 (質問は後からでも "編集" できます)

VSCodeプラグイン
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions
デプロイに成功している判断材料
Deploy Successedと出ているため
